# How to open PDF in new window using ng2-pdf-viewer in angular2?

Tags: npm, angular2-directives, pdf-viewer

I want to open pdf document in new window using ng2-pdf-viewer in angular2.
I have shown pdf url on hyperlink,when user clicks on it,this should open and show the pdf in new window.

Also I want to make sure that pdf is not downloadable.

Please suggest the solution.